# How to compare a varchar field having "(" character

Tags: sql, sql-server

If a field value in the table of SQL Server is like **A(B)** and if I to write a query

`SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyField = 'A(B)'`

it is not returning any result. How to handle this situation?

Comment: Your query seems fine and should work. Are you sure that the value is `A(B)`?, not trainling spaces?. What happens if you do `MyField LIKE '%A(B)%'`?

Comment: @Lamak That is not working. Answer is given below.

Comment: You would have an issue if you used `like` instead of `=` and square brackets `A[B]` instead of parenthesis `A(B)`. Did you mean that you have a problem with `where MyField like 'A[B]'`.

Comment: Why downvote after so many days? Moderators should look at this. Without reason a downvote should not be encouraged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query should work fine, if you want to specify a different escape parameter, you can use [`ESCAPE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx).

```
WHERE column LIKE '%A#(B#)%' ESCAPE '#'
```

Also, if you want to match anything that contains "A(B)", don't forget to surround it by percetages symbols.